# trig functions with imaginary numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to write some code in javascript to calculate trig functions, inverse trig functions, and hyperbolic trig functions with imaginary numbers. I have the sin, cos, sinh, and cosh working well. However, I am having some trouble getting my solutions for others to match the only verification that I can find at [this site](http://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/complex-number-calculator.html).

For example, below is the code for asin(x+yi). I am using the formula located [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalLogarithm.html) along with the definitions for modulus and argument found there as well. It has no errors, but doesn't match the results from the site I cited. What am I doing wrong?

asin(z)=-i*ln(iz+sqrt(1-z^2))

```
var id1=SquareComplex (window[id].Solution_real, window[id].Solution_imag);     
var real=1-window[id1].Solution_real;
var imag=window[id1].Solution_imag;
var id2=SquareRoot(real, imag); 
imag=window[id].Solution_real+window[id2].Solution_imag;
real=-window[id].Solution_imag+window[id2].Solution_real;
var modulus=Math.sqrt(real^2+imag^2);
var argument=Math.atan2(imag,real);  
var Solution_imag=-Math.log(modulus);
var Solution_real=argument;
```

This code is intended to work in several steps. The first line calls a function that squares the complex number z. The second and third lines subtract the result from the number 1. The fourth line calls a function to take the square root of the complex number. The fifth and sixth lines add the results of the previous actions to the result of multiplying the complex number by i. The remaining lines get the modulus and argument of those results, take the natural logarithm, and multiply it by a negative i.

Comment: Your use of `window` in that code is pretty bizarre, and it's not clear what's going on.

Comment: Have you thought about creating an object for complex numbers that you can pass about rather than having to pass the real and imaginary parts separately? It strikes me that this would make things much easier to read...

Comment: In _JavaScript_, `^` is a _bitwise XOR_ and does not mean the next number is an exponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first three lines are:

```
var id1=SquareComplex (window[id].Solution_real, window[id].Solution_imag);     
var real=1-window[id1].Solution_real;
var imag=window[id1].Solution_imag;
```

assuming that `id` is your initial `z` then this is not calculating the real and imaginary parts of `1-z^2` as I believe it is indtended to. The reason being that the imaginary part isn't being subtracted.

Try it with

```
var imag = -window[id1].Solution_imag;
```

and see if that helps. I can't guarantee there aren't any more errors in it but I'd suggest just going through and being really careful about making sure each line does what it should.

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem along with the fact that "squaring" the numbers was not working and I had to use the Math.pow function.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [math.js](http://mathjs.org), which comes with support for complex numbers for all functions including trigonometry:

```
var value = math.complex(2, 3);
var ans = math.asin(value);
```

Or using the expression parser:

```
var ans = math.eval('asin(2 + 3i)');
```